# Running an SQL query into a gridview for a table with 55 million row.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Here's my problem: I built a small ASP.Net site to display some data from one of our internal databases. I have it set that the Query runs on a button click and takes into account parameters entered into 4 different text boxes. This all works just fine if I limit the query to the top 1 million or so rows. The issue is that my table has a bit over 55 million rows. If I take off the limiter I'm constantly getting overflow and memory errors. I'm not surprised, but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this. I was wondering if maybe the parameters are only applying themselves AFTER the query has been run. Sorry if I'm being inexact, I only started doing this stuff last week. Here's my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<span class="style1">

<strong>Date </strong>(dd/mm/yyyy)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="14/08/2009" style="margin-left: 4px" 
    Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; TO&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="125px" Text="30/12/2012" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<span class="style1"><strong>Trans #&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></span>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 94px" 
    Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<strong><span class="style1">Part &nbsp; </span></strong>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" style="margin-left: 117px" 
    Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<br />
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    style="text-align: center" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="C6946_TRANS_TYPE" HeaderText="Type de Transaction/Transaction Type" 
            SortExpression="C6946_TRANS_TYPE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="C6946_TRANS_DATE" 
            HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Date de Transaction/Transaction Date" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"
            SortExpression="C6946_TRANS_DATE" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
           >
```

"

```
SelectCommand="SELECT C6946_TRANS_TYPE, C6946_TRANS_DATE, C6946_SO, C6946_LATE_FLAG, C6946_TRANS_NUM, ALIGNED_PART_NUMBER, C1001_ENG_PART_NUMBER, C6946_PART_KEY, PART_DESCRIPTION, C6946_RECORD FROM DWH.AIXW2S_T6946_TRANS_IMS"

    FilterExpression= "C6946_TRANS_NUM LIKE '%{0}%' AND (C6946_PART_KEY LIKE '%{1}%' OR ALIGNED_PART_NUMBER LIKE '%{1}%' OR C1001_ENG_PART_NUMBER LIKE '%{1}%')  AND C6946_TRANS_DATE >= #{2}# AND C6946_TRANS_DATE <= #{3}#">
<FilterParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="C6946_TRANS_NUM" PropertyName="text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="C6946_PART_KEY" PropertyName="text"  Type="string"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4" Name="C6946_TRANS_DATE" PropertyName="text"  Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox5" Name="C6946_TRANS_DATE" PropertyName="text"  Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
        </FilterParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: There's no possible use for a UI element with a million rows, let alone 55million rows. Think about what the user might do with such a thing. It's almost entirely useless. Even touching a scrollbar will move you thousands of rows at a time.

Comment: @spender +1 @user1902070 You should consider a way to paginate the results (`limit` and `offset` in SQL) and provide a way for the user to search or filter the dataset.

Comment: There is no element with a million rows. There are limiters in place that the user fills out before running the query. Most should reduce to, at most, a few hundred rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could be hitting the memory limit in a 32-bit worker process (if that is what you are using). Even if this went through, the browser would probably crash. This would be better suited and more realistic for a desktop application.

Comment: Damn, I didn't realize it would be an issue. Like I said, I've never done anything like this before. I told my boss as much, he just said: I have confidence in your abilities. Any other words of advice?

Answer (score 0):

You may need an architecture redesign. A paged query to the database (via a REST API call perhaps?) to pull in the desired records, or perhaps a NoSQL alternative if you are running into query performance issues when performing JOINs between tables of such size.

Comment: Unfourtunetly I have no clue what any of that means, when I say I'm new at this, I mean I have literally never done anything coding wise beyong C++. I'm a mechanical engineer, not a CS guy. And, to be honest, I think the entire thing is ridiculous. Even using SQL Server Management it takes upwards of 10 minutes to run a full query on the table...